# Generate a Typed OData Client With the OData Generator: Autogenerated code does not compile with SAP library

Tags: java, odata, sap-cloud-sdk

I generated the code using a maven plugin and the code does not compile.
https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java
I am using the odata V2 Plugin

I am not sure how to resolve this compilation issue:

**The method getHttpClient(String) in the type HttpClientAccessor is not applicable for the arguments (HttpDestinationProperties)**

Here is my pom file.

> ```
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.sap.cloud.s4hana.datamodel</groupId>
>           <artifactId>odata-core</artifactId>
>           <version>2.28.0</version>           </dependency>
>
>
>           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->            <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
>           <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
>           <version>1.18.22</version>          </dependency>
>           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->           <dependency>
>           <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
>           <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
>           <version>1</version>            </dependency>
> ```
>
> com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel
>       odata-generator-maven-plugin
>       3.59.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referring to correct documentation but the version number is your pom is incorrect.

In the documentation, it says 3.x.x, which as of 10.12.2022 would be [3.59.0](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#3590---december-02-2021).

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel</groupId>
    <artifactId>odata-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- Please use the latest version here-->
    <version>3.XX.X</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-consumption</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputDirectory>${project.basedir}/edmx</inputDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/vdm</outputDirectory>
                <deleteOutputDirectory>true</deleteOutputDirectory>
                <packageName>com.mycompany.vdm</packageName>
                <defaultBasePath>odata/v2/</defaultBasePath>
                <compileScope>COMPILE</compileScope>
                <serviceMethodsPerEntitySet>true</serviceMethodsPerEntitySet>
                <!-- (Optional) You can add a custom copyright header:
                <copyrightHeader>Copyright (c) this year, my company</copyrightHeader>

                Or use the SAP copyright header:
                <sapCopyrightHeader>true</sapCopyrightHeader>
                -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It feels like you're using an existing project based on an outdated and deprecated SDK version. Could you try generating a new project and use the maven plugin from there?

You can also check out if the service you're going to use has a pregenrated client library on the SAP API Business Hub. Check this one for example https://api.sap.com/api/API_COSTCENTERACTIVITYTYPE_SRV/cloud-sdk/Java